# How can I configure my USB sound card with KDE tools?

Tags: 14.04, usb, kubuntu, kde, external-soundcard

I have a USB soundcard which is detected by the system (as output in `/proc/asound/cards` and by `lsusb`).  However, it is not selectable in KDE settings.  It shows up in the list of sound cards, but is greyed out and unselectable.

I wonder how I can make sure this card is selectable when I plug it in.